How to view the build log of a Unity APK build on Mac from the file Editor.log?
I am running Unity 2022 (LTS) on Mac.
A few days ago, I was able see the APK build log inside the file Editor.log.
But, today, after building a new APK successfully, I open the file Editor.log. This file has some info, but I don't see any info about the build at all.
Would you please tell me how to fix this ?
Is there any option I need to enable inside the Build window, Publishing Settings, or Other Settings ?

I found out the solution: I just need to restart Unity.
That solves the issue.
